# Counting in Tuple Relational Calculus

Tags: relational-theory, database-theory, relational-calculus

Given the following schema:

- Staff (**sid**, sname)
- Project (**pid**, pdesc, pfrom, pto)
- Asset (**aid**, acat, adesc)
- Workfor (**sid, pid**, wfrom, wto)
- Assignment (**aid, sid, pid**, afrom, ato)

Note: The **bold** attributes are the keys.

Find the names of the staffs who worked or are working for more than one project, in Tuple Relational Calculus.

I was thinking of using count() but it is not allowed in TRC (or according to my Prof). Any answers appreciated.

Comment: *"working for more than one project"* = "working for two projects (or more)" = "working for two different projects". Does that help?